# strange behaviour of git

Tags: linux, git, iptables, gitosis

i have strange behaviour of git - push is working, but clone is not :(

```
alec$ git clone git://host/repo.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/alec/Temp/repo/.git/
host[0: x.x.x.x]: errno=Connection refused
fatal: unable to connect a socket (Connection refused)
```

whats wrong?

Comment: Perhaps the `host` isn't running a git daemon or perhaps it's just refusing connections from your client. Without knowing the details of your configuration it's difficult to tell.

Comment: Tell us what push says too... that should include the repository url, which might be ssh: instead of git:.  In which case, if you use the same url as worked with push, you should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push is probably working over SSH (port 22) but clone works over the git port (port 9418). You  (or your network admin) will have to open this port if you want to be able to clone repositories.

Comment: You can clone over ssh if you have ssh access and read permissions on the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Github or Bitbucket (Sourcetree) apps. They usually have less errors, and do most of everything that the command line does. I use bitbucket because their GUI git app is complex and provides many options.

Bitbucket http://bitbucket.org
GitHub http://github.com